# The accelerometer sensor of Samsung S21 works irregularly in android 12

Tags: android, c++, samsung-mobile, android-12

I created a small program to draw a line by accelerometer sensor in my Samsung S21. But when the phone updates to android 12, my program doesn't work sometimes. I found the reason is that the accelerometer sensor event doesn't work.

This is init function

```
const int LOOPER_ID_USER = 3;
const int SENSOR_HISTORY_LENGTH = 100;
const int SENSOR_REFRESH_RATE_HZ = 50;
constexpr int32_t SENSOR_REFRESH_PERIOD_US = int32_t(1000000 / SENSOR_REFRESH_RATE_HZ);
const float SENSOR_FILTER_ALPHA = 0.1f;
void init(AAssetManager *assetManager) {
        AAsset *vertexShaderAsset = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, "shader.glslv",
                                                       AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
        assert(vertexShaderAsset != NULL);
        const void *vertexShaderBuf = AAsset_getBuffer(vertexShaderAsset);
        assert(vertexShaderBuf != NULL);
        off_t vertexShaderLength = AAsset_getLength(vertexShaderAsset);
        vertexShaderSource = std::string((const char*)vertexShaderBuf,
                                         (size_t)vertexShaderLength);
        AAsset_close(vertexShaderAsset);

        AAsset *fragmentShaderAsset = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, "shader.glslf",
                                                         AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
        assert(fragmentShaderAsset != NULL);
        const void *fragmentShaderBuf = AAsset_getBuffer(fragmentShaderAsset);
        assert(fragmentShaderBuf != NULL);
        off_t fragmentShaderLength = AAsset_getLength(fragmentShaderAsset);
        fragmentShaderSource = std::string((const char*)fragmentShaderBuf,
                                           (size_t)fragmentShaderLength);
        AAsset_close(fragmentShaderAsset);

        sensorManager = AcquireASensorManagerInstance();
        assert(sensorManager != NULL);
        accelerometer = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(sensorManager, ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        assert(accelerometer != NULL);
        looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
        assert(looper != NULL);
        accelerometerEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(sensorManager, looper,
                                                                  LOOPER_ID_USER, NULL, NULL);
        assert(accelerometerEventQueue != NULL);
        auto status = ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(accelerometerEventQueue,
                                                     accelerometer);
        assert(status >= 0);
        status = ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(accelerometerEventQueue,
                                                accelerometer,
                                                SENSOR_REFRESH_PERIOD_US);
        assert(status >= 0);
        (void)status;   //to silent unused compiler warning

        generateXPos();
    }
```

This is update function

```
void update() {
        ALooper_pollAll(0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        ASensorEvent event;
        float a = SENSOR_FILTER_ALPHA;
        int status = ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(accelerometerEventQueue, &event, 1);
        while (status > 0) {
            sensorDataFilter.x = a * event.acceleration.x + (1.0f - a) * sensorDataFilter.x;
            sensorDataFilter.y = a * event.acceleration.y + (1.0f - a) * sensorDataFilter.y;
            sensorDataFilter.z = a * event.acceleration.z + (1.0f - a) * sensorDataFilter.z;
            status = ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(accelerometerEventQueue, &event, 1);
        }
        sensorData[sensorDataIndex] = sensorDataFilter;
        sensorData[SENSOR_HISTORY_LENGTH+sensorDataIndex] = sensorDataFilter;
        sensorDataIndex = (sensorDataIndex + 1) % SENSOR_HISTORY_LENGTH;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Are you fixed this problem? Same issue. :)

Comment: I "solved" the problem. I have the Unity engine, but maybe this will help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/input-acceleration-on-android-12-sometimes-doesnt-work.1259133/